# Number of possible mismatches on a chain comparing with other

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of mismatches that you can find comparing one chain to another.

Let's say $k$ denotes the number of mismatches, $A$ denotes the alphabet that I can use (for example, on DNA I have the alphabet $\{\text{C}, \text{G}, \text{A}, \text{T}\}$ so the cardinal of my alphabet is $4$) and $n$ denotes the length of my chain.

I have obtained the following formula:

$n=8, k=2, \#A=4$

$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m(\#A-1)^k=\sum_{m=1}^7m(4-1)^2$$

Is this correct? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  The sum should go to $n$ because you can be mismatched at all the positions.  If you are mismatched at $m$ positions, you need to choose which those are, not just multiply by $m$.  What is $k$?  You did not define it.